# pgfplots, change legende image style

Tags: pgfplots

I'd like to plot data marks and a linear regressions for two data sets in the same plot and add a legend entry for one data/regression pair:
Here is my current state:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotstableread[col sep = comma]{
  x,   y1,      y2,
  1,    1.0,     3.0,
  2,    2.2,     6.3,
  4,    3.9,    10.0,
  8,    8.1,    25.0,
  } \data
 \begin{document}
  \begin{figure}
   \centering
   \begin{tikzpicture}
     \begin{axis}[legend pos=north west,
          legend image post style={solid}
       ]
       \addplot[only marks,mark=o,color=red] table [x=x, y=y1] {\data};
       \addplot[no markers,color=red,forget plot] table [x=x, y={create col/linear regression={y=y1}}] {\data};
       \addlegendentry{y1}
       \addplot[only marks,mark=square,color=blue] table [x=x, y=y2]{\data};
       \addplot[no markers,color=blue,forget plot] table [x=x, y={create col/linear regression={y=y2}}] {\data};
       \addlegendentry{y2}
     \end{axis}
   \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{figure}
 \end{document}
```

It creates the following image:

[image: Legend without lines :(]

I'd like to have a line and a mark for each single legend entry, but currently only the marks appear. How can I draw the lines as well? 
When I change the described plots to the line plots (i.e. moving the 'forget plot' option one line up), I guess I can not add different marks according to each entry in the legend, can I?
Thanks,
    Juhui

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can change the plot options used for generating the legend image using the `legend image post style` key:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotstableread[col sep = comma]{
  x,   y1,      y2,
  1,    1.0,     3.0,
  2,    2.2,     6.3,
  4,    3.9,    10.0,
  8,    8.1,    25.0,
  } \data
 \begin{document}
   \begin{tikzpicture}
     \begin{axis}[legend pos=north west,
          legend image post style={solid}
       ]
       \addplot[only marks,mark=o,color=red, legend image post style={sharp plot}] table [x=x, y=y1] {\data};
       \addplot[no markers,color=red,forget plot] table [x=x, y={create col/linear regression={y=y1}}] {\data};
       \addlegendentry{y1}
       \addplot[only marks,mark=square,color=blue, legend image post style={sharp plot}] table [x=x, y=y2]{\data};
       \addplot[no markers,color=blue,forget plot] table [x=x, y={create col/linear regression={y=y2}}] {\data};
       \addlegendentry{y2}
     \end{axis}
   \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```

Comment: Hi Jake, that's it, thank you very much. You provided two ways to get what I wanted: add the "sharp plot" instead of solid in the legend image post style that I had, and how I can set the legend image style for a single plot. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is this actually a line of best fit?

Comment: @Magpie: Why wouldn't it be?

Comment: The excel/calc line of best fits are not real so you need to use a LINEST command to figure out the actual line of best fit. This is done by minimising $\chi^2$. I am just wondering if this is the case here too (i.e how it is calculated).

Comment: @Magpie: Yes, PGFPlots uses a least squares regression. The parameters for the first regression found by PGFPlots are `a=1.00174, b=0.0043474`, using R's `lm` command finds `a=1.00174, b=0.04348`, so I'd say the method used by PGFPlots is valid.

Comment: @jake This is almost too good to be true. What code did you use to call the parameters from pgfplots?

Comment: @Magpie: After you do the regression, the regression parameters are saved in two macros `\pgfplotstableregressiona` and `\pgfplotstableregressionb`.